# How to reduce the gap cause <br>

Tags: html, css

How can i reduce the "gap" or the "space" cause by the `<br>` on this CSS because it is too much ...
also it is really noticeable on actual web browser on PC so here's a [live demo](https://glxqnkricwnbjmke.000webhostapp.com/error_handler.htm)
thank you ..

```css
.alert {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: Tomato;

  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, Tahoma, Trebuchet, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">You must read and agree to the Terms and Conditions agreement. </div><br>
<div class="alert">That email is already connected to an account!</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really be using line breaks for this purpose. Just add a bottom margin to the .alert class and remove the line break.

```
<div class="alert">You must read and agree to the Terms and Conditions agreement. </div>
<div class="alert">That email is already connected to an account!</div>

.alert {
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: Tomato;

  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, Tahoma, Trebuchet, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/74qaxr2z/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `br` tag, and use `margin-bottom` instead.
See the following example.

**HTML**

```
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Another way to do this is using the CSS grid. This way, you don't need to remove the margin of the last div (if needed) using extra CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
  <div>Your contents</div>
  <div>Your contents</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `<br>` tag from html and instead put both alerts in a parent `div` and add margin to it.

```css
.alertparent{
  margin:5px;
}
.alert {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: Tomato;

  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, Tahoma, Trebuchet, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="alertparent">
  <div class="alert">You must read and agree to the Terms and Conditions agreement. </div>
</div>
<div class="alertparent">
    <div class="alert">That email is already connected to an account!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need the `<br>`tag. You can assign the DIVs a margin-bottom.

```css
.alert {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: Tomato;

  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, Tahoma, Trebuchet, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">You must read and agree to the Terms and Conditions agreement. </div>
<div class="alert">That email is already connected to an account!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

divs are already block-level elements which means by default it takes the full width of the browser. So whenever a div is added it automatically falls to a new line. If you want to explicitly add a space between them try using this

```css
.alert {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: Tomato;

  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, Tahoma, Trebuchet, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: block;
}

.alert:first-child{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">You must read and agree to the Terms and Conditions agreement. </div>
<div class="alert">That email is already connected to an account!</div>
```